# Solve using Lagrangian method

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Solve using Lagrangian method:

$ Maximize \   \ \ (x^2+2y^2-x) \ $ with respect to $ \ x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \ $

Find the $ \ 5 \ $ pairs $ \ (x,y) \ $ that satisfies Lagrangian equations.

**Answer:**
Let $ \ f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2-x \ $ and $ \ g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1=0 \ $

Let $ \ \lambda \ $ be the lagrangian multiplier.

Then,

$ \nabla f(x)=\lambda \nabla g(x) \\ \Rightarrow \\ 2x-1=2 \lambda x \ \\ 4y=2 \lambda y $

For $ \ y=0 \ $ the second equation satisfies.

Then,  $ g(x,0)=0  \Rightarrow x^2=1 \ \Rightarrow x=\pm \ $

Thus the two critical points are $ \ (\pm1,0) \ $

Next, we have to find rest $ \ 3 \ $ critical points.

From the first equation , we have

$ 2x-1=2 \lambda x \ $

But how to find other $ \ 3 \ $ critical points in order to get all $ \ 5 \ $ critical points.

Help me

Comment: What about $({ 1\over 2}, 0)$? Why do you presume that $\lambda \neq 2$?

Comment: This will give more 2 points. But we need more 1 point according to the question.

Comment: What about $x=-{1 \over 2}$, and $y$ chosen to satisfy the constraint?

Comment: These are just suggestions, it is not entirely clear to me what the question is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the question is to find all possible points that satisfy the
necessary first order conditions of optimality.

There are two cases to consider:

(i) $x^2+y^2 <1$, in which case we have $2x-1 = 0, y=0$ which yields $({1 \over 2},0)$.

(ii) $x^2+y^2 =1$. Then the Lagrange conditions give
$2x-1=2 \lambda x$, $2y= \lambda y$, or $2x(1-\lambda) = 1$, $(2-\lambda)y = 0$.

Case (a) $\lambda = 2$: Then $x = -{1 \over 2}$ and $y= \pm {\sqrt{3} \over 2}$.

Case(b) $\lambda \neq 2$: Then $y=0$ and $x \pm 1$.

Counting all of these gives five solutions.

Note that since we are maximising, we must have $x\le 0$, so there are really
only three solutions to consider, and a quick evaluation shows that the
maximisers are $(-{1 \over 2},\pm{\sqrt{3} \over 2})$.